# How to view files in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am building an iPhone app that can save email attachments. I would like to be able to view the files from inside the application as well. I need to be able to view as many kinds of files as possible: .txt, .pdf, .png, .jpeg., .doc, .xls, etc.

The files will reside inside of my application's documents folder. What is the best solution for this? My first thought is to convert my file-paths to URLs and load them in a UIWebView, but I'm not sure if this is the best way, or if it will handle all those file types. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Apple's own Mail app does this is with the QuickLook framework. I'd suggest you do the same. QLPreviewController does all the heavy lifting for you. You can also use UIDocumentInteractionController; this is still using QuickLook behind the scenes to generate the preview.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave this a shot, but when the controller launches, i see nothing and get this warning:
    "warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/DisplayBundles/Image.qldisplay/Image (file not found).
warning: No copy of Image.qldisplay/Image found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session."   Any suggestions?

Comment: @user: Working example at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-4-Book-Examples/tree/master/p736p754fileHandoff

Comment: @matt The link has move, the correct link is now: [https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples).

Answer (score 2):

The UIWebView is the best way to show this kind of file.

Alternatively you can try to read the document in an other app with this code:

```
        UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:document.documentURL] retain];
        interactionController.delegate = self;
        BOOL canOpenDocument = [interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(365, 200, 300, 400) inView:self.view animated:YES];

        if(!canOpenDocument) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Your phone can't read this kind of file, please install an app from appstore for that" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
```

Comment: If all he wants to do is show a preview, it is silly to hand the document off to another application if QuickLook already knows how to display it. Instead of using UIDocumentInteractionController to hand off the document to another app, he should use UIDocumentInteractionController to stay right where he is and display the preview! This is in fact the same as using QLPreviewController.